# asymptotes of a hyperbola

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, graphics

Im trying to do a hyperbola with the a tangent in the middle, more or less like this, centered in x=4 and y=3
[image]

but I can get only this
[image]

the MWE is

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{datavisualization.formats.functions}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \datavisualization[
    school book axes,
    visualize as smooth line/.list={left,right},
    x axis={length=6cm, ticks and grid={major also at=4}},
    y axis={length=6cm, ticks={some}},
    data/format=function
  ]
    data[set=left] {
      var x : interval [0:3.9] samples 84;
      func y = 1 / (\value x - 4);
    }
    data[set=right] {
      var x : interval[4.1:8] samples 84;
      func y = 1 / (\value x - 4);
    };
    \addplot [mark=none,draw=violet,ultra thick,smooth,domain=0:360] {-1*tan(\x)};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

I usually give the trigonometric functions arguments in degress, but lately it seems to work without a domain, and went well too.
But this time seems not to work the tangent-
The main problem is that I cant work the hyperbola to get up to y=3.
Perhaps it is needs to declare the axis section, but I wonder if this will conflict with the custom definitions of the hyperbola thingys.

Comment: You just need to add 3 to the expression for y; then, when x goes to infinity, y goes to 3.

Comment: I was doing that way, but the asypmtotes remained the same

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I propose the solution below.  It is based on `pgfplots`.
[image]

- I tried to figure out the functions you are interested in from your code.
- It is a good practice to use the same technique for similar things (here the two graphs).
- It is better to give the domain for your graphs; in this way, you control what you are doing.

**The code**

```
\documentclass[border=1cm]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[
    font=\scriptsize,
    axis background style={fill=gray!5},
    grid=major,
    grid style={color=gray!50},
    xtick={0,1,...,8},
    ytick={-6,-3,...,12},
    axis lines=center
    ]
    \addplot[mark=none, draw=violet, thick, smooth,
    domain=-.2:{.86+pi/2}, samples=100] {-tan(deg(x-1))};
    \addplot[mark=none, draw=violet, thick, smooth,
    domain={1.08+pi/2}:{.86+3*pi/2}, samples=100] {-tan(deg(x-1))};
    \addplot[mark=none, draw=violet, thick, smooth,
    domain={1.08+3*pi/2}:8.2, samples=100] {-tan(deg(x-1))};
    
    \addplot[mark=none, draw=red, thick, smooth, domain=-.2:3.9, samples=100]
    {1/(x-4) +3};    
    \addplot[mark=none, draw=red, thick, smooth, domain=4.1:8.2, samples=100]
    {1/(x-4) +3};    
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks so much,the first time I try to do this , I was thinking it would be easy,but unexpectedly, it was so hard to crack down, with the hyperbola never get to level up it and the tangent was a matter or try and error,do you use some method to aproximate a expression for the function based on the graph?

Comment: Hi. No method really; I've just noticed that the green graph in the image you posted was similar to -tan(x) and that the value at 1 was 0. Maybe your problems were implied by the different ways you were handling the two graphs; there were different "coordinate systems" involved.